# raspberry pi home automation sphinx

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh, home-automation, raspberry-pi-desktop

[image: pocketsphinx-5prealpha]

Hello.
I'm suffering from this problem. Had anyone here dealt with it before, if so please help me. I'm running out of the time.

I already downloaded `cont_ad.h` to sphinxbase library but nothing has changed. Anyway, I'm afraid that the version of the file that I downloaded doesn't match with the version of sphinxbase that I have.

Concerning the guide I'm following, it is a book by Richard Grimmett called Raspberry Pi Robotic Projects.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you forgot to include the "cont_ad.h" file in your "sphinxbase" directory, therefore you compiler is not able to do its job.  Perhaps you can give us the weblink to the installation guide you are following.

Comment: Yeah, you're right but I already  downloaded that file to sphinxbase library but nothing has changed. Anyway, I'm afraid that the version of the file that I downloaded doesn't match with the version of sphinxbase that I have!??

Comment: Concerning the guide I'm following, it is a book by Richard Grimmett called Raspberry Pi Robotic Projects.